# NSURLCache not caching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsurlcache

So I have subclassed `NSURLCache` and every time I call `loadHTMLFromString:` it calls `storeCachedRequest:forRequest:` and then `cachedResponseForRequest:`. Here's what I have:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSString *pathString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    NSCachedURLResponse * response = [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    if (response != nil)
        return response;
    else {
        NSString* myString= @"testing";

        NSData* data=[myString dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding ];

        //
        // Create the cacheable response
        //
        NSURLResponse *response =
        [[[NSURLResponse alloc]
          initWithURL:[request URL]
          MIMEType:[self mimeTypeForPath:pathString]
          expectedContentLength:[data length]
          textEncodingName:nil]
         autorelease];
        NSCachedURLResponse * cachedResponse =
        [[[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:data] autorelease];

        [self storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:request] ;

        //NSLog(@"DEFAULT CACHE WITH URL %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
        return [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)storeCachedResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse forRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    [super storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:request];

    NSLog(@"STORE CACHED RESPONSE WITH URL %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
}
```

The issue is that when I call `cachedResponseForRequest:` right after it is saved, the response is always nil. Why is this?

I had:

```
NSURLRequest * req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageSource_]];
NSCachedURLResponse * response = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:req];

if (response == nil)
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE IS NIL");
else {
    NSString* theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response.data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE IS NOT NIL %@", theString);
}
```

and it always prints response is nil. The url string is the same as it was when it 
`storeCachedResponse`. For some reason it is not caching. I've set the cache size to some amount of size.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but I think you need to use the `NSURLResponse` that got returned by your `NSURLConnection` instead of creating your own. My suspicion is that if you just create a `NSURLResponse` it doesn't have any headers set for the caching, and so `NSURLCache` assumes it should cache this particular result.

Comment: hmmm... are you sure about that? because storeCachedResponse was called right before cachedResponseForRequest and response == nil in that method

Comment: so even if I am not creating my own NSURLResponse, it still doesn't saves it

Comment: "hmmm... are you sure about that?" Read the first three words of my answer again. ;-)

Comment: Does your server send out the proper cache headers?

Comment: yes it does, anyway I decided to just use SDURLCache and it works much better

Answer (score 1):

The default NSURLCache seems to be pretty random when choosing what to cache or not. Your best bet may be to subclass it and handle caching of the files you mind directly in cachedResponseForRequest: and leaving the rest for super.